# Can I travel to Italy with two passports: an EU passport and non EU?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, airports, italy

I am going on a school trip next week to Rome, Italy. The flights were booked before the summer in May, using my Filipino passport. But over the summer I received my EU passport (I am living in Ireland, so I'm an Irish citizen). I was wondering if I can still fly to Italy without a visa on my Filipino passport since I have my EU passport?

Comment: Contact your school and ask if your ticket was made out on your Filipino passport, if so, bring it, but also bring your Irish passport as that allows you to enter without visa, use the 'EU passports' lines on arrival and can avoid visa questions which are not needed as you are an EU citizen.

Comment: As a personal anecdote, I have an American passport and an Italian one, and when I travel to Europe I bring both, so I can avoid the slow lines. I've never had any trouble with airlines requiring one or the other; in my experience, they just care that the information matches. Ditto for customs lines.

Answer (score 12):

You will have to go through two *separate* checks of your documents, one before boarding and one after arrival.

- **Airline employees** will try to make sure that all passengers have the right to enter the destination country before the airplane departs. If they fail to do so, the airline will be fined, and the airlines have established their own administative procedures for these checks.
- **Immigration officials** will make the actual decision if you can enter the destination country after the aircraft has landed.

For the second check, your Irish passport is all you need. For the first check, your Filipino passport may be necessary because that is what the airline's database says. The airline employees *should* accept the Irish passport instead of the visa. You can't board with just your Filipino passport and no visa, of course.

---

@phoog etc, as I understand it there is a Filipino passport without visa and an Irish passport, so she cannot use just the Filipino passport, but the airline expects to see the Filipino passport.

Comment: I've upvoted this answer because it's the clearest so far about the distinction between the airline and immigration officials. In my experience, however, the airline won't need to see the Philippine passport. Obviously this could vary from one company to another, but I have commonly used a different passport from the one already on record with the airline, and nobody has ever said anything. Clearly it's a good idea to have the Philippine passport ready in case they want to see it, of course.

Answer (score 5):

In short, yes.  I am a dual national of an EU and a non-EU country, and I routinely carry both passports, though I usually show only one or the other at any point in my trip.

You don't need a visa because you're an EU citizen. You should be able to make the trip entirely with your Irish passport. If you're worried about the airline because you've given them your Philippine passport number, then bring that along, too, and show it to them if they ask.  But I doubt they will; mostly they just care that the name matches and that you're allowed to enter your destination.

When you cross the border, show your Irish passport to the border officers.

Comment: Thank you so much! My school hasn't gotten back to me about it and made me worry a lot. The trip means a lot to me and I'm really glad I can still go.

Comment: @DeniseBelen as an Irish citizen, and therefore an EU citizen, you may want to read up on freedom of movement, currently under directive 2004/38/EC, which gives you a legal right to travel to every EU country, and a few others besides.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when booking flights no passport information is given but only name. Therefore it isn't a problem to use any passport on your name. My friend regularly uses two passports in the same trip - one to leave our country and another one to enter the destination country

You will not be able to enter Italy with your Filipino passport if you don't have a visa, however if you use your Irish passport for the flight then there is no need for a visa

Comment: Italy requires a visa and my ticket was issued using my Filipino passport. Will it matter to them if I even bring my EU passport with me?

Comment: @DeniseBelen you don't need a visa because you have an EU passport!